# How to accept and parse a list of json objects using fetch

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a quick search on the site. To make a request to the server and get a response I use fetch. But unfortunately I still don't understand javascript very well. I wrote a little code for this but I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 172
Promise.then (async)        
ser @   Search.js:27
onkeyup @   (index):65




function ser(element) {
    const input = element.value;
    document.getElementById('sugg').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('field_sear').style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "0";
    document.getElementById('field_sear').style.borderTopLeftRadius = "0";

    if (input !== '') {
        fetch('/search', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(input)
        }).then((result) => {
            return result.json();
        }).then(resBody => {

            if (resBody.length === 0) {
                const div = document.createElement('div');
                div.className = 'nothing-search';
                div.innerHTML = 'Не найдено';
                document.getElementById('sugg').appendChild(div);
            }
else {
                resBody.forEach(function (suggested) {
                    const div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.innerHTML = suggested.id;
                    div.innerHTML = suggested.name;
                    div.innerHTML = suggested.urlPictures;
                    div.innerHTML = suggested.price;
                    document.getElementById('sugg').appendChild(div);
                });
            }
            if (input === '') {
                document.getElementById('field_sear').style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "30px";
                document.getElementById('field_sear').style.borderTopLeftRadius = "30px";
                document.getElementById('sugg').innerHTML = '';
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Apparently I get a response from the server but I don't understand how to parse it

```
 {"id":"600d6f8b4a9384ee4210a394",
        "name":"Речицкий уезд 18 век",
      "urlPicture":"https://drive.google.com/ucexport=download&id=1HolWGhxT9vZ2geiU4q9gM4974iVIRjuh",
"price":"10"}
```

there are about 10 of them

Comment: The text at the bottom can be `JSON.parse`d successfully. I think there is a malformed character somewhere below or something, can you post the full response from the server? It says `Unexpected token { in JSON at position 172`, so need at least 172 characters

Comment: If there are 10 stanzas like that, then that is the problem: you can't do that in JSON without wrapping them up as an array.

Comment: The full server response is 615 characters,( this is too much for a comment)

Comment: @Rebel-cat you can edit your question.

Comment: yes, indeed, before I sent just a long string with json from the server. Now I have done that an array of string json is sent from the server. And the error disappeared, although "undefined" is returned for each element in the search bar"

Comment: I'm not making myself clear.  We need to see **all** of the server response edited into your question.  The error you're getting happens after that stanza you posted (which has no error in it). It might also help if you'd post the server code that creates the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your ‘/search’ fetch,  JSON.parse(result);

Comment: The response content is already being parsed, and it has a JSON syntax error in it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to parse a huge json from a dozen objects and the "JSON.parse" method can only decompose from " {"to "}" and since it was "," it gave an error. The correct option:

```
function ser(element) {

    const input = element.value;
    document.getElementById('sugg').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('field_sear').style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "0";
    document.getElementById('field_sear').style.borderTopLeftRadius = "0";

    if (input !== '') {
        fetch('/search', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(input)
        }).then((result) => {
            return result.json();
        }).then((res) => {
            if (res.length === 0) {
                const div = document.createElement('div');
                div.className = 'nothing-search';
                div.innerHTML = 'Не найдено';
                document.getElementById('sugg').appendChild(div);
            } else {
                res.forEach(function (suggested) {
                    let obj = JSON.parse(suggested);
                    const div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.innerHTML = obj.id;
                    div.innerHTML = obj.name;
                    div.innerHTML = obj.urlPictures;
                    div.innerHTML = obj.price;
                    document.getElementById('sugg').appendChild(div);
                });
            }
            if (input === '') {
                document.getElementById('field_sear').style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "30px";
                document.getElementById('field_sear').style.borderTopLeftRadius = "30px";
                document.getElementById('sugg').innerHTML = '';
            }
        });
    }
}
```